# CSS3 hover over buttons

Tags: html, css

Hello can anyone help me i have this buttons and i want to make the transition off each one of them when i put my mouse over each one but seems to work only for the first button even that each button have a different class. seems that :hover dont work for all.

CSS code:

```
.first{
    width:10%;
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;
    border:2px solid black;
}

.second{
    width:10%;
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;
    border:2px solid black;
}

.last{
    width:10%;
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;
    border:2px solid black;
}

#type{
    border-radius:100%;
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #2EFEF7;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4em;
    transition:2s;
}

#type1{
    border-radius:15%;
    border:none;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #01A9DB;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4em;
    transition:2s;
}

#type2{
    border:none;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #0404B4;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4em;
    transition:2s;
}
    .first:hover #type{
    transition:2s;
    left:0;
};

    .second:hover #type1{
        transition:2s;
        left:0;
    };

    .last:hover #type2{
        transition:2s;
        left:0;
    };
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>buttons</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#F6CED8">
<!-- <div clas="gen"> -->
    <div class="first">
        <button type="submit" id="type">Click Here!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <button type="submit" id="type1">Click Here!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="last"> 
        <button type="submit" id="type2">Click Here!</button>
    </div>
<!-- </div> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all delete `;` semicolons after braces `}`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4L3ec/

I changed the width and height to 100px instead of % , b.c I couldn't even see the buttons without that. But the fiddle I posted works great now.

```
.first {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border:2px solid black;
}
.second {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border:2px solid black;
}
.last {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border:2px solid black;
}
#type {
    border-radius:100%;
    border: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #2EFEF7;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4em;
    transition:2s;
}
#type1 {
    border-radius:15%;
    border:none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #01A9DB;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    transition:2s;
    left: -4em;
}
#type2 {
    border:none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0404B4;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    transition:2s;
    left: -4em;
}
.first:hover #type {
    transition:2s;
    left:0;
}
.second:hover #type1 {
    transition:2s;
    left:0;
}
.last:hover #type2 {
    transition:2s;
    left:0;
}
.body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is not valid. Remove the extra `;` after the `}` and it will work

```css
.first {
    width:10%;
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;
    border:2px solid black;
}
.second {
    width:10%;
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;
    border:2px solid black;
}
.last {
    width:10%;
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;
    border:2px solid black;
}
#type {
    border-radius:100%;
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #2EFEF7;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4em;
    transition:2s;
}
#type1 {
    border-radius:15%;
    border:none;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #01A9DB;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4em;
    transition:2s;
}
#type2 {
    border:none;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #0404B4;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4em;
    transition:2s;
}
.first:hover #type {
    transition:2s;
    left:0;
}

 .second:hover #type1 {
    transition:2s;
    left:0;
}

 .last:hover #type2 {
    transition:2s;
    left:0;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9S26n/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/UrELy/) answer for that.

```
.first{
    width:10%;
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;
    border:2px solid black;
}

.second{
    width:10%;
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;
    border:2px solid black;
}

.last{
    width:10%;
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;
    border:2px solid black;
}
#type {
    border-radius:100%;
    border: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #2EFEF7;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4em;
    transition:2s;
}
#type1 {
    border-radius:15%;
    border:none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #01A9DB;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    transition:2s;
    left: -4em;
}
#type2 {
    border:none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0404B4;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    transition:2s;
    left: -4em;
}
.first:hover #type {
    transition:2s;
    left:0;
}
.second:hover #type1 {
    transition:2s;
    left:0;
}
.last:hover #type2 {
    transition:2s;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Ty for help problem was ;. :)